# How to shift a value when using SQL in python

Tags: python, sql, for-loop, if-statement

Picture: Misaligned columns: [image]

Please refer to the picture linked above. I have an email report showing negative values with parentheses around them. I need to make it do that the last digit in each number lines up with each other. The values are being printing by using for-loops and if-statements when running SQL statements. The values are printed as they run through the SQL statements.

How do I get the positive values to shift once to the left to align with the last digit of the numbers in parentheses?

Here are the for loops that print the columns in the report:

```
m1_total=0
m3_total=0
m6_total=0
m12_total=0


for line in curs:
    if (line[1]==0) or (line[1]==None): #skip if the M1 is 0
        continue


    m1=0
    m3=0
    m6=0
    m12=0
    if line[1]>0:
        m1=line[1]
    if line[2]>0:
        m3=round(line[2]/3)
    if line[3]>0:
        m6=round(line[3]/6)
    if line[4]>0:
        m12=round(line[4]/12)
    mc3=0
    mc6=0
    mc12=0
    if m3 > 0:
        mc3=round((m1/m3)*100-100,2)
    if m6>0:
        mc6=round((m3/m6)*100-100,2)
    if m12 > 0:
        mc12=round((m6/m12)*100-100,2)


    outStr+=str(line[0]).ljust(13,'.')+round_dolls(m1,9)+round_dolls(m3,9)+round_dolls(m6,9)+round_dolls(m12,9)
    outStr+=round_dolls(mc3,14,'d')+round_dolls(mc6,9,'d')+round_dolls(mc12,9,'d') + '<br>'
    m1_total+=m1
    m3_total+=m3
    m6_total+=m6
    m12_total+=m12
    mc3_total=0
    mc6_total=0
    mc12_total=0
    if m3_total > 0:
        mc3_total=round((m1_total/m3_total)*100-100,2)
    if m6_total>0:
        mc6_total=round((m3_total/m6_total)*100-100,2)
    if m12_total > 0:
        mc12_total=round((m6_total/m12_total)*100-100,2)

    if line[-1] != ')':
        str(m12) = str(m12)[:-1]
```

The last two lines are where I tried to implement the solution, but it didn't work.

Here is the method that puts the negative numbers in parentheses:

```
def format_num(num,justLen,justWithChar='.',howManyDecimal=0,putComma='Y',minusFormat='-',zeroChar='0'):
    if not num:
        num = 0

    if num == 0:
        if zeroChar <> '0':
            return zeroChar.rjust(justLen,justWithChar)

    roundedNum = round(num, howManyDecimal) # rounded becomes float
    if putComma=='Y': # put comma at thousand
        numStr = '{:,}'.format(roundedNum) # fractional part is truncated to 5 decimal place
    else:
        numStr = str(roundedNum)
    if howManyDecimal == 0:
        numStr = numStr.rsplit('.')[0] # 1,234.99 -> ['1,234', '99']
    else: # to pad with 0 ex) 4234.9 -> 4234.90
        numStr=numStr.rsplit('.')[0] + '.' + numStr.rsplit('.')[1].ljust(howManyDecimal, '0')

    if num < 0:
        if minusFormat=='P': # change - sign to parenthesis format
            numStr = numStr.replace('-', '(') + ')'

    return numStr.rjust(justLen,justWithChar)
```

Here is the code from round_dolls():

```
def round_dolls(num, justLen, format='I', zeroChar='0'):
    if format == 'Q': # quantity - no comma - 99999
        return format_num(num, justLen, '.', 0, 'N','-',zeroChar)
    elif format == 'I': # integer - 99,999
        return format_num(num, justLen, '.', 0, 'Y','-',zeroChar)
    elif format == 'F': # float wit 2 decimal places - 99,999.99
        return format_num(num, justLen, '.', 2, 'Y','-',zeroChar)
    elif format == 'D': # 99,999 negative number (99,999)
        return format_num(num, justLen, '.', 0, 'Y','P',zeroChar)
    elif format == 'd': # 99,999.99 negative number (99,999.99)
        return format_num(num, justLen, '.', 2, 'Y','P',zeroChar)
    elif format == 'P': # percentage
        return format_num(num*100, justLen, '.', 0) + '%'
    else:
        return 'Format not specified'
```

Comment: Where in that code is it changing negative values to use parentheses?

Comment: If the number is positive, print it with a space afterward. This will line the last digit  with the last digit of numbers in parentheses.

Comment: And also reduce the number of `.` before it by 1.

Comment: @barmar where would I put the space after the positive value in the code?

Comment: It probably needs to be in the `round_dolls()` function.

Comment: @barmar I added the code of where the negative values are changed. I didn't know where that code was before.

Comment: There are no calls `format_num()` in the loop. Is it called by `round_dolls()`?

Comment: I was wondering that myself, I'm not sure how it's called. It's not called in round_dolls() either

Comment: Maybe it's called by something else that `round_dolls()` calls. But if it's called, my answer below should work.

Comment: Assigning to `str(m12)` makes no sense. You can't assign to the result of a function call.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change:

```
if num < 0:
    if minusFormat=='P': # change - sign to parenthesis format
        numStr = numStr.replace('-', '(') + ')'
```

to:

```
if minusFormat == 'P':
    if num < 0: # change - sign to parenthesis format
        numStr = numStr.replace('-', '(') + ')'
    else: # add extra character to positive values to line up with negative
        numStr = numStr + justWithChar
```

If you don't want a `.` in the last character of the line, you can put this after the `for c in range(len(line))` loop to remove the character if it's not `)`:

```
if rowStr[-1] != ')':
    rowStr = rowStr[:-1]
```

Comment: It works, but it adds a "." at the end of the last column, printing numbers like "123.45."

Comment: That's because `+ justWithChar`. Isn't everything execpt the values supposed to be those fillder characters?

Comment: `format_num()` doesn't know it's the last number on the line, so it can't format it differently. If you find the code that calls it, it could remove a `.` at the end.

Comment: Actually, I see it is called in round_dolls(). I added the code up top. I'm not sure how to tell it to not include the period if the column is the last one.

Comment: You don't. At the end of the original loop, check if the last character in `rowStr` is a period and remove it.

Comment: Why don't you want a period in the last column? If the negative values have a `)`, shouldn't there be a period in that place to line up properly?

Comment: It looks odd, I want to replace it with a space at the end. I'll try to check for the period at the end. Thank you!

Comment: I'm having trouble finding how to check the last column. I'm only seeing how to check the last row.

Comment: I realized that this particular method (ShippingAverages) does not call MultiLineOutput and has its own for-loop in it. Unfortunately, I cannot find a way to implement your solution to that for-loop. I changed the first for-loop in the question to the correct one.

Comment: Are you saying that the code you posted earlier is not the code that you're having trouble with? You should post a new question, not completely rewrite this question so my answer no longer applies.

Comment: No, the code you gave me solved the original issue but caused the one about the period at the end of the last column. I only realized that the original for-loop wasn't used at all, but your original answer was put in FomatNum anyway

Comment: I don't understand why the same solution doesn't work with the correct loop. Just remove the last character of `outStr` if it's not a `)`.

Comment: You need to do that before you append `<br>` to the line.